# Prime factorization and modulo for large exponents

Tags: prime-numbers, contest-math, prime-factorization

Given that $7xy7xy...7xy$ is a multiple of $143$ where there are $2008$ occurrences of $7xy$. Find the values of $x$ and $y$.

I know that $143$ is a semiprime with factors $1, 11, 13, 143$. How should I proceed to break down the large exponent in order to check if the modulo would be zero?

Comment: **Note :** $\underbrace{7ab7ab\cdots7ab}_{2008 \text{ times }} \ne 7ab^{2008}$

Comment: @TheDemonix_Hermit Thank you! Corrected as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $1001= 7 \times 143$.

Your number is $(700+10a+b)\times 1001 \times (\sum_{i=0}^{1003} 10^{6i})$.

> So any values of $a$ and $b$ will do.

Comment: Hi Donald, thanks for the reply. May I know if the significance of 1001 is for me to get a recurring 3 digit sequence? If so, how does that tie in with the third term of the equation that you've provided so that I can, with the justification of 1001 having a factor of 143, prove that a and b can be any number?

Comment: $1001 \times (100+7a+b)=7ab7ab$ (written in decimal) Now multiply by $(1+10^6+ \cdots + 10^{1003})$ to get your number. So, yeah, $1001$ will divide your number & hence $143$ will also.

Answer (score 1):

Use *congruences*: $\;10^3\equiv -1\mod 143$, so
$$\underbrace{7ab\,7ab\,\dots\,7ab}_{2008\text{ times}}=\sum_{k=0}^{2007}7ab\,(10^3)^k\equiv7ab\sum_{k=0}^{2007}(-1)^k=0,$$
because there is an even number of $(-1)^k$ terms, so any values for $a$ and $b$ are fine.